# flutter: run panel doesn't detect my emulators on mac in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, runtime

i am new to mac and i wanna test my flutter code on emulators first, i have just downloaded android studio and build my AVD's, however the run panel on the top wont read my emulators, altho i run flutter doctor and it says (one connected device found) and i also can run my code on the emulator via the terminal of android studio when i type flutter run, whats causing this issue of the run then?

[image]

[image]

Comment: on the terminal try `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server`. Now use `adb devices` to see the emulators. IDE should auto detect emulators. Try intergrated terminal in the IDE.

Comment: tried it. but it didn't seem to work. "adb devices" and "flutter devices" works. but the same issue still taking place in Android Studio Run Panel.

Answer (score 0):

The 'run panel' will not list emulators that you have not already executed.

An icon on the upper right side of the main tool bar is AVD manager.  Select that icon or go to the tools menu and select AVD maanger.  From the AVD manager select the 'run' icon on the right side for the emulator your wish.  Once execution begins, the emulator will show in your 'run panel'.  It may have a name that looks odd but it is there.

Also note that while the Android Studio 'run panel' will list iOS simulators by the device name (eg. iPnone SE2), it will list Android emulators with odd names with no relation to the device name in AVD.

Comment: Dear, the emulator is already running. but the button that shows the emulator name next to the run button has a hover -over text saying " Not applicable for the main.dart configuration".

Comment: Close the emulator and use the process outline to open it again.

Comment: please explain further about "process outline" , i didn't understand. i tried running Pixel 2 with Android Q on it. it's saying the same. The dropdown menu for selecting Devices keeps saying Loading. i have re-installed android SDK and flutter from git, same issue still. using "adb devices" and "flutter devices" works in the terminal inside AS. also flutter run in the terminal works. but Android Studio it self seems to fail to detect any running devices. i tried using Breakpoints as indicated [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/pull/4014) here but it didn't work. any ideas?

Comment: Try this:  Close ALL emulators.  Next, using the AS menu, select tools.  From there, select AVD manager.  AVD manager will display a list of configured virtual devices.  For the virtual device you want to run, click the right pointing triangle showing under action on the right side of AVD.  Once the emulator is running, you will see the virtual device listed in the 'run panel'.  It is the drop down left of the 'MAIN.DART' configuration.

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded Xcode and set up a simulator. that made both the emulator and simulator work.